# Select, Handle and Insert/Update JSON data type

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I am using a Node.JS server with a MySQL database and I just realised that MySQL supports JSON as a data type.

Based on my previous statement how do I a) `SELECT` `JSON`, b) handle results in my node.js code and c) then `UPDATE`the DB entries again in `JSON`?

Code example for parts a and b:

```
sql.getConnection((err, con)=>{
            con.query("SELECT test FROM test", (error, row)=>{
            con.release();
            if(error) throw error;          
            console.log(row[0].test);
            });
});
```

this snippet of code returns: `{"entryid": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}}`,

now if i try to do something like this: `console.log(row[0].test./*any sub-key here*/);` it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to resolve my issue simply by ignoring MySQL's recommended syntax and implementing my own evil methods as you can see in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Valamorde/f819a05569a93420cc3144bd5fcd63f7).

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
let dbconn = {
    host: "localhost",       // make sure to replace with your own configuration
    user: "root",            // make sure to replace with your own configuration
    password: "password",    // make sure to replace with your own configuration
    connectionLimit: 100,    // make sure to replace with your own configuration
    database: "db"           // make sure to replace with your own configuration
};
let sql = mysql.createPool(dbconn);
let jsonObj;
 /*
    * let's assume that the stored JSON has the following structure:
    *
    * "master_key" : {
    *      sub_key1: "test1",
    *      sub_key2: "test2",
    *      sub_key3: {
    *          sub_key4: "test4"
    *      }
    *  
*/

sql.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    // We can SELECT it
    conn.query("SELECT json_Column FROM test_Table",(error, row) => {
        conn.release();
        if(error) throw error;
        jsonObj = JSON.parse(row[0].json_Column); //you can now handle the json keys as usual
        // jsonObj.master_key || jsonObj.master_key.sub_key1 || jsonObj.master_key.sub_key3.sub_key4 || however you want
    });

    // We can INSERT it
    jsonObj = {/*your JSON here*/};
    conn.query("INSERT INTO test_Table(json_Column) VALUES ?", [JSON.stringify(jsonObj)],(error, row) => {
        conn.release();
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log(row[0]);
    });

    // We can UPDATE it
    jsonObj = {/*your JSON here*/};
    conn.query("UPDATE test_Table SET json_Column = ?", [JSON.stringify(jsonObj)],(error, row) => {
        conn.release();
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log(row[0]);
    });
});
```